# Link database table in combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datagrid, combobox

Hello guys I have a big problem where I cant solve myself so I ask this with you guys.

I have a combobox name(cbox1), datagridview name(dtgrid1) and 2 tables in mysql named(tbl2013 and tbl2014)
heres the question.

1. How can i link the database table(tbl2013 and 2014) in my combobox?
2. How can i load the database table data in the datagrid?

for example I choose the tbl2013 how can I load their table data into datagrid?

I need your help guys.
I always deleting my codes in c# because it always give me error message.

Comment: yeah. but it gives me the same result

Comment: First add your work what you have done to load table into grid.

Answer (score 1):

Take table list from database

```
  SELECT name  
  FROM sys.tables
```

Above query gets the table names, get it to a datasource and bind to combobox, and in the combobox `selectedIndexChange` event call Bindgrid and pass combobox selected value to Bindgrid method

```
void BindGrid(string sTable)
{
  string sqlQuery = "select * from " + sTable ;
  // Exec query and get data to Datatable dtResult
  datagrid.Datasorce = dtResult;
  datagrid.bind();
}
```